# How to Show currently logged in User's Name in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, real-time, google-tag-manager

I am able to fetch user names using GTM and set it to a GA custom dimension, so that I can see who is doing what. Its perfectly working.
But, I am not getting the User Names at Real Time. Can anyone tell me how I will be able to see User Names in Real Time? I am ready to do any kind of customization for this.
Any help will be appreciate!!

Comment: You can use a filter to copy the value of the custom dimension to another data field that is displayed in realtime (e.g. campaign source etc), or overwrite the data field in code (via a "set" call). However that means you lose that data field for reporting, so you should do that in a distinct view. Also take care that the user name does not reveal the real identity of the user, else you are in violation of Google TOS.

Comment: This would violate the usage guideline for analytics. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795983?hl=en

Comment: The [Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) only supports a subset of dimensions and metrics, plus its against Google Analytics TOS to send PII to GA.